# How to hande a curl response fail in Bash script

Tags: bash, curl

How can I handle request fails in this example of bash curl requests. I.e. if all servers are responde with JSON all is okay and I have JSON file at end of a cycle. But if one of this servers not responde with JSON or not responde at all I do have nothing in "/data.json" file, even all other servers are working perfectly. How can I catch a server fail and skip it?

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG=config.json

jsondata=data.json

i=1
echo "{ \"success\": \"OK\", \"servers\": {" > $jsondata
jq -r '.servers|keys[]' $CONFIG | while read key ; do
    if [ "$i" -ne "1" ]; then
        echo "," >> $jsondata
    fi
    echo "\"server$i\": {" >> $jsondata

    RESPONSE=$(curl -s $HTTP://$IP:$PORT/api)
    DATA1=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq '.data1')
    DATA2=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq '.data2')

    echo "  \"data1\": $DATA1", >> $jsondata
    echo "  \"data2\": $DATA2", >> $jsondata
    echo "}" >> $jsondata
    ((i++))
done

echo "}," >> $jsondata
```

Comment: Where are you using `key` that you read from `$CONFIG`? You probably want to separate the calls to `curl` from the actual generation of the JSON (and use `jq` to generate the JSON instead of constructing it manually).

Comment: `key` it's a dynamical number of servers.

Comment: `response=$(curl --fail ...) || continue`, if you just want to skip to the next item. (BTW, the lowercase variable name is intentional -- all-caps names are used for variables built into the shell, lowercase names are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to conflict; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's assume we have a function to make a single API call.

```
do_api () {
  key=$1
  curl $HTTP://$IP:$PORT/api  # Presumably, key is needed here somewhere
}
```

I'll also assume that the intended output is a JSON object that has *at least* two fields, `data1` and `data2`. Now, we can write a simple pipeline with three stages:

1. Read keys from `$CONFIG`
2. Make an API call for each key
3. Generate the desired output from the combined output of all the API calls.

It's not too complicated:

```
jq -r '.servers | keys[]' |                       # stage 1
  while read key; do do_api "$key"; done |        # stage 2
  jq -s 'to_entries |         
          map({key: "server(\.key+1)", 
               value: {data1: .value.data1, 
                       data2: .value.data2}
              }) |
         {success: "OK", servers: from_entries}'  # stage 3
```

`do_api` should output nothing for a particular key of `curl` fails, but you can modify it to produce some sort of default data if you wish:

```
do_api () {
  key=$1
  curl --fail ... || jq -n '{data1: null, data2: null}'
}
```

---

`jq -s 'to_entries'` takes an input like

```
{ "data1": ..., "data2": ... }
{ "data1": ..., "data2": ... }
```

(which is what we expect from `curl`), and produces as output

```
[ { "key": 0, "value": { "data1": ..., "data2": ... } },
  { "key": 1, "value": { "data1": ..., "data2": ... } }
]
```

The `map(...)` filter takes the preceding array and produces the keys and values we want to add to the `servers` object in the final result, which is created by a call to `from_entries`.

---

Here is a full example. `tmp.json` contains the simulated output of `do_api`, complete with an extra field `data3` that will be filtered from the final output.

```
$ cat tmp.json
{
    "data1": "foo",
    "data2": "bar",
    "data3": "baz"
}
{
    "data1": "hello",
    "data2": "world",
    "data3": "bye"
}

$ jq -s 'to_entries | map({key: "server\(.key+1)", value: {data1: .value.data1, data2: .value.data2}}) | {success: "OK", servers: from_entries}' tmp.json
{
  "success": "OK",
  "servers": {
    "server1": {
      "data1": "foo",
      "data2": "bar"
    },
    "server2": {
      "data1": "hello",
      "data2": "world"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest making it explicit that the `curl` arguments contain `--fail` if we want exit status to be nonzero in the event of a server-side issue (500, 404, etc).

Comment: Thank you guys! I've added `--connect-timeout 2` for better experience.